# How should I structure Project Task lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, task-list, content-and-structure

I've been asked to create a project and task list within a SharePoint Online site. It seems simple but I want to ensure I have a workable and maintainable structure.

**Base requirements:**

- The site will contain multiple projects.
- Each project will have one or more tasks.
- Project status will be determined by a roll-up of the project-specific task list.
- An overview page will show all of the projects and roll-up statuses.

I thought this could be achieved by using a single Task list. A top level task for a Project then as sub-tasks as required. However, I can't see a way to have different fields for the top level task and the sub-tasks.

Any suggestions on how I can structure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create task list in SharePoint online, the top-level task and sub task have the same fields by default. It is by design.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Manage Tasks List in SharePoint Online.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/manage-tasks-list-in-sharepoint-online/

If the task list cannot meet your requirement, you could store the projects and tasks in two lists. Then you can add different columns for the projects and tasks.

And you can establish the connection between the two lists by unique and lookup columns. 
For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632